# Satake Diagram determines Involution

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\theta$ and $\tau$ be involutions of a semisimple complex lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and suppose that they have the same Satake diagram.  I want to understand why they must be conjugate to one another.

Let $\mathfrak{t}_-$ be a maximal torus in the $(-1)$-eigenspace of $\theta$, and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra containing $\mathfrak{t}_1$.  Then I see that we can conjugate $\tau$ by an automorphism $\sigma$ so that  $\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma|_{\mathfrak{h}}=\theta|_{\mathfrak{h}}$.  It will then follow that $(\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma)\circ\theta$ fixes $\mathfrak{h}$ and further fixes the centralizer of $\mathfrak{t}_1$ (since both $\theta$ and $\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ fix it individually).  But this doesn't imply it's the identity map, of course, or even that it's conjugate to the identity (since there are many automorphisms that fix a Cartan pointwise without being conjugate to the identity).

So I'm stuck there.  Any help/ideas?

Edit: For clarification, by involution of $\mathfrak{g}$ I mean an automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ as a complex lie algebra which is not the identity but composes with itself to the identity.

Satake Diagram: if $\theta$ is an involution of $\mathfrak{g}$, then we can write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{k}$ is the (+1)-eigenspace of $\theta$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is the $(-1)$-eigenspace of $\theta$.  Choosing a maximal torus $\mathfrak{t}_1\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e. a maximal abelian subspace consisting of semisimple elements inside $\mathfrak{p}$), we can extend this to a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, and choose a Borel by taking a regular element $\gamma\in\mathfrak{t}_1^*$ and perturbing it slightly to a regular element in $\mathfrak{h}^*$.  For such a choice of Cartan subalgebra and Borel, we take the corresponding Dynkin diagram from simple positive roots $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ and do the following: if $\alpha_i|_{\mathfrak{t}_1}=0$, color the node for $\alpha_i$ black.  If $\alpha_i|_{\mathfrak{t}_1}\neq0$ color the node for $\alpha_i$ white. 
 If $\alpha_j|_{\mathfrak{t}_1}=\alpha_k|_{\mathfrak{t}_1}\neq 0$, then connect the nodes for $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ by arrows.  The resulting diagram is called the 'Satake diagram' of $\theta$, and is well-defined.

Reference: 'Homogeneous Spaces and Equivariant Embeddings' by D.A. Timashev.

Comment: Could you explain or give a reference for what you mean by an involution of the complex algebra, and its Satake diagram?

Comment: Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: An idea: Consider a "Borel pair" $\frak h\subset\frak b\subset\frak g$. There exists an *inner* automorphism $g\in {\rm Inn}(\frak g)$ such that $g\circ\theta$ takes $(\frak h,\frak b)$ to itself and thus defines an automorphism $\theta_*$ of the Dynkin diagram $D(\frak g,\frak h,\frak b)$, which does not depend on the choice of $g$. I suspect that you can compute $\theta_*$ from the Satake diagram of $\theta$. On the other hand, if $\tau_*=\theta_*$, then $\tau=g\circ\theta$ for some inner automorphism $g$ of $\frak g$. Is this what you need?

Comment: That's not quite what I want.  I want $\tau=\sigma\circ\theta\circ\sigma^{-1}$ for some automorphism (not necessarily inner) $\sigma\in Aut(\mathfrak{g})$.   i.e. I want $\tau$ and $\theta$ to be conjugate in the group $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$.
And it's not true that conjugacy classes of automorphisms (or involutions) are determined by the induced diagram automorphism.

Comment: In fact, as I mentioned in my question, there are involutions that fix a Cartan subalgebra pointwise but are not the identity.

Comment: It seems to me that, if $\sigma$ is the complex conjugation, the elements fixed by $\theta \circ \sigma$ resp. $\tau \circ \sigma$ are real forms of $\mathfrak{g}$ which are uniquely determined up to isomorphism by the resp. Satake diagram. Since these are the same, there is a real isomorphism between them, and I guess this lifts to the one your are looking for, which conjugates $\theta$ and $\tau$. I'll think through it more later.

Comment: That's interesting.  Is it easy to see why $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear involutions are determined up to isomorphism by their satake diagrams?  Because that would be my next question.

Comment: Note that conjugacy classes of involutions of complex simple Lie algebras are classified by Kac diagrams. See Table 7 in the book: Onishchik and Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, Springer 1990. For the corresponding theory see Onishchik and Vinberg (Eds.), Lie Groups and Lie Algebras III, EMS vol. 41, Springer 1994.

Comment: Concerning relations between $\Bbb C$-linear and $\Bbb C$-antilinear involutions, see [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05956)

Comment: Table 9 of Onishchik and Vinberg 1990 lists Satake diagrams of real forms of simple complex Lie algebras. On page 274 of this book it is written: This table quite easily implies **Theorem 3.** Two semisimple Lie algebras over $\Bbb R$ are isomorphic if and only it so are (in the natural sense) their Satake diagrams.

Comment: That the Satake diagram determines the iso class of a form of a semisimple Lie algebra (or, by Galois cohomology, the class of your $\theta$ in $H^1(Gal(\mathbb{C}|\mathbb{R}), Aut (\mathfrak{g})$) is a quite involved theorem. (It goes back to Borel-Tits for reductive groups and Satake for real Lie groups: for the Lie algebra setting my thesis on this will be published soon.) Maybe if one goes through the constructions in this case, there is an easier route. How much of Cartan theory is one allowed to use? E.g. can we assume the fact that there is a unique compact form up to isomorphism?

Comment: But obviously you will have to use some "classifying property" of Satake diagrams because that is the only extra information linking $\theta$ and $\tau$ in the assertion.

Comment: The preprint linked by Mikhail Borovoi (thanks!) is quite enlightening. Also look at example 4.16 in [this earlier version](http://www.liegroups.org/tables/galois/galois.pdf). So my earlier comment is to be taken with a grain of salt, your $\theta$ and $\tau$ live in a different $H^1$ which however, as explained in that preprint, is isomorphic to the one I wrote. (And I finally understand that in the Cartan-involution description, people take the *compact form* as the basepoint of their $H^1$, whereas coming from a Galois viewpoint, one takes the *split form*.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: This depends on the base field. Over a general field one starts from the split form, but over $\Bbb R$ one starts from the compact form. See my texts (with co-authors) on Galois cohomology over $\Bbb R$: [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4362) and [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06252).